# Splitting algorithm for survival tree in rpart package

Tags: survival, cart, rpart

I'm modeling Survival Tree using the package $\fbox{rpart}$ in R.

Do you know which **splitting criterion** is used in this package to build the tree ?
I tried to look at its document but it seems that the author does not mention how the tree is splitted.

Thank you!

Comment: Have you looked at the code itself, not just the manual? Availability of the source code is an important advantage of R.

Comment: @EdM: thanks for your suggestion, i 'm having a look at it

Comment: If you find an answer in the code, please post it here as a guide to others. It's OK to answer your own question and to accept it as the preferred answer (although you might have to wait a couple of days to accept it).